# Libgit2 after merging MERGE_HEAD still present in .git folder

Tags: c++, merge, commit, libgit2

After merging files from a remote repository and local, and commiting this merge, i ve still have the following files : MERGE_HEAD, MERGE_MODE, MERGE_MSG

Is that a normal behavior and i need to clean them manuallz, or did i do something wrong ?

As if i call git status in this folder, git status answer that there are a merge pending.

[Source code of how i do pull merge commit](https://gist.github.com/khertan/9a3a7d6ff8e068795a61#file-notesmodel-cpp-L130)

thx

EDIT : Snippet of how i do the pull merge commit[Pull Merge Commit](https://gist.github.com/khertan/9521e1b89837b3382eac)

Comment: `git_commit` should handle clearing that data for you. Can you post a snippet of code?

Comment: Snippet added : https://gist.github.com/khertan/9521e1b89837b3382eac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files are there for compatibility with git. Creating a new commit does not automatically remove them, as they should only be removed once the application has determined that the update happened successfully and fully.

There is a function for cleaning up the state, [git_repository_state_cleanup()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_state_cleanup) which you can call once you've created the merge commit and updated the reference.